# Create a Select statement that determines a duration between 2 dates split out to each of the 2 dates

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with records that contain the following columns: 
Taskname, Start_Date, End_Date

I need to add a new column that shows the Duration between Start_Date and End_Date.
If a tasks overlaps multiple days I would need to create a split of duration for each of the dates

Example:

Start_Date = 4-6-2020 23:45:00 End date = 5-6-2020 00:00:16

Results 2 records showing the duration for each of the days:

```
4-6-2020   15
5-6-2020   16
```

Thank you for looking at my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need a calendar table to return the days within the interval. You may already have one, if not I've made an example with a [CTE](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-server-dates-table-using-tsql-cte-calendar-table.aspx) as calendar.

After that we return an UNION, with the Start_Date and the minutes between Start_Date and End_Date if they are on the same day, or the minutes until next day. Adding the full days of the interval (the days within Start_Date + 1 and End_Date -1) with 24 * 60 minutes each. And finally adding the End_Date with the minutes from the previous day when it's a different day than Start_Date

```
create table MyLog (Start_Date datetime, End_Date datetime)
insert into MyLog (Start_Date, End_Date)
            values ('2020-06-04 23:45', '2020-06-05 00:16')

declare @Start_Date date = (select min(Start_Date) from MyLog)
declare @End_Date date = (select max(End_Date) from MyLog)

;
with CTE as (
  select @Start_Date as date
  union all
  select dateadd(day, 1, date) as date
  from CTE 
  where date < @End_Date
)
select convert(date, Start_Date) as date,
       case when convert(date, Start_Date) = convert(date, End_Date) then datediff(minute, Start_Date, End_Date)
            else datediff(minute, Start_Date, dateadd(day, 1, convert(date, Start_Date)))
       end as minutes
from MyLog
union all
select CTE.date, 
        24 * 60 as minutes
from MyLog
     inner join CTE on CTE.date between dateadd(day, 1, convert(date, Start_Date)) and dateadd(day, -1, convert(date, End_Date))
union all
select convert(date, End_Date) as date,
        datediff(minute, convert(date, End_Date), End_Date) as minutes
from MyLog
where convert(date, Start_Date) <> convert(date, End_Date)
```

See it [online](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cef9eb21c888a093e9dabf32f61b2fde)